# D3 - Change stacked bar chart from clicking on legend

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/7Eg34HyhXY6M3UJccAFq?p=preview

Its a simple stacked bar chart

I wanted to be able to click on a color in the legend and update the chart to show just that bar only

Ive found a few examples online but they are a bit too complex - just needed a simple method if thats possible

```
let legendItems = legend.selectAll('li')
    .data(legendKeys)
    .enter()
    .append('li');

legendItems.append('span')
    .attr('class', 'rect')
    .style('background-color', (d, i) =>{
        return colors[i];
    });

legendItems.append('span')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .html((d) => {
        return d
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind `click` event handler this way:

```
let legendItems = legend.selectAll('li')
    .data(legendKeys)
    .enter()
    .append('li')
    .on('click', handleLegendItemClick);
```

Handler-function should looks like this (pay attention on the comments):

```
function handleLegendItemClick(d, i) {
  // change opacity to show active legend item
  legendItems.filter(legendItem => legendItem !== d).style('opacity', 0.5);
  legendItems.filter(legendItem => legendItem === d).style('opacity', 1);

  // update domain of y scale and update tick on y axis
  y.domain([0, stackedSeries[i][0].data[d]]);
  yAxis.transition().call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // bind new data
  let enter = rects.data([stackedSeries[i]])
    .enter()
    .append('rect');

  // remove old rects
  rects.exit();

  // draw new rect
  rects.merge(enter)
    .attr('height', (d) => {
      return height - y(d[0].data[d.key]);
    })
    .attr('y', (d) => {
      return 0;
    })
    .style('fill', (d, i) => {
      return colorScale(d);
    });
}
```

Check [this fork of your plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LmxDGbSAcqKmUXdKA0gh?p=preview). (I also add color scale - `colorScale` for applying a color by legend key name, not by index as you did.)

```
const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(colors);
colorScale.domain(legendKeys);
```

Comment: If I add more data to create further stacked bars it seems to break the code - https://plnkr.co/edit/XvIvicHRHvZDTethDuxF?p=preview